# Pagination not working for list in grails

Tags: grails, pagination

Pagination is not working for me in grails.I am not able to see the pagination buttons in the GUI as well.I am seeing the whole list  in the GUI

```
def lists={
params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 10, 100) 
def submittedList=[],InstanceList=[]
submittedList=FicheRequest.executeQuery("select fr.id,fr.MOSSNumber from FicheRequest fr where  fr.status=?",['Submitted']) 
    if(submittedList.size()>0){
    def sortedSubmittedList=new MossNumberSorting().getSortedMossNo(submittedList as ArrayList[])
    sortedSubmittedList.each{sortedId->InstanceList.add(FicheRequest.get(sortedId))}
            }
    else
    flash.message="No Submitted Request exists in the queue"

    return [InstanceList:InstanceList, InstanceTotal: InstanceList.count()] 
}
```

and in the gsp I am using

```
<div class="paginateButtons">
            <g:paginate total="${InstanceTotal}" />
        </div>
```

I am also seeing the max and offset parameter in the URL

```
http://localhost:9090/apps2/lists?offset=0&max=10
```

Not sure where is the problem,please suggest some solution

Answer (score 0):

You have probably forgotten to pass params to line:

`submittedList=FicheRequest.executeQuery("select fr.id,fr.MOSSNumber from FicheRequest fr where  fr.status=?",['Submitted'])` 


try like this:
`submittedList=FicheRequest.executeQuery("select fr.id,fr.MOSSNumber from FicheRequest fr where  fr.status=?",['Submitted'],[max:params.max,offset:params.offset])`
See more details:
http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html

Comment: Nope,that does not help,getting the same result.I am passing InstanceList to the view,which is a list of all the instances of FicheRequest.

Comment: So, what do you want exectly? Describe the task.

Comment: I already mentioned what I want as above,do you want more detailed explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I found a rough solution for paginating my array list. I can pass the complete list with the max and offset value and obtain the list that I want to show in my view:

http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2010/09/14/grails-pagination-on-filtered-list/

but this is not a good solution as it requires loading all the database values for pagination. One solution that comes to my mind is to store the domain instances in moss number sorted format. Well the format of the moss number is little bit complex; that's why I am using the Comparator class to sort it after retriving all the instance from the DB. I welcome better ideas on how I can save my instances in moss number sorted format, or anything else.